# Compatibility of twin paradox with the time-dependent Hubble constant

Tags: special-relativity, space-expansion, twin-paradox

The universe is currently expanding with a speed of about 70 km/sec/Mpc which is today's Hubble constant. As this expression includes two length units, it is also possible to use the unit: $sec^{-1}$, and I obtain the following value: $$\frac{2,3 * 10^{-18}}{sec}$$ (considering only one space dimension), that is in percentage per second: $$\frac{2,3  * 10^{-16} \%  }{sec}$$

As a result, any space expands at a certain percentage per second, space expansion is time dependent.

**My question: How can time dilation of special relativity be compatible with such a time dependent parameter?**

Example: Alice is making a space travel while Bob stays on Earth. When she comes back, Bob has become 20 years older while Alice aged only by 5 years. Question: by what percentage increased space in the meantime, a) from the point of view of Alice, and b) from the point of view of Bob?

Or: For how many years did space increase at the rate  $\frac{2,3  * 10^{-16} \%  }{sec}$ ?

Comment: Just a minute! Does our Earth swell? Are there such data? If the universe is expanding, does that mean that our planet does that too? Or it only means that the swelling happens only far from us?

Comment: There is no reason to panic:[_the model is valid only on large scales (roughly the scale of galaxy clusters and above). At smaller scales matter has become bound together under the influence of gravitational attraction and such things do not expand at the metric expansion rate as the universe ages._](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_expansion_of_space)

Comment: Special relativity is NOT the correct theory of the geometry of the universe.

Comment: Time is not an absolute but a relative value. Is a time dependent parameter such as Hubble constant fit for representing the geometry of the universe? That is my question.